# The getter 'uid' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: uid Flutter Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

i am sending userID to Profile Page from Selector Page. The error appears once and then disappears. But the app works. Debug console say the error is related with the selectorPage. I think there's a problem in the userInfo function.

here is my selectorPage: I am sending the currentUser to ProfilePage

```
final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
User1 currentUser;

class SelectorPage extends StatefulWidget {
  SelectorPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SelectorPageState createState() => _SelectorPageState();
}

class _SelectorPageState extends State<SelectorPage> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  PageController _pageController;
  AuthService authService = new AuthService();

  Future<void> userInfo() async {
    print("It's work!");
    final User gcurrentUser = auth.currentUser;
    DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot =
        await usersReference.doc(gcurrentUser.uid).get();

    if (!documentSnapshot.exists) {
      print("there's no data");
    }
    setState(() {
      currentUser = User1.fromDocument(documentSnapshot);
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    setState(() {
      userInfo();
    });
    super.initState();
    _pageController = PageController();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _pageController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SizedBox.expand(
        child: PageView(
          controller: _pageController,
          onPageChanged: (index) {
            setState(() => _selectedIndex = index);
          },
          children: <Widget>[
            HomePage(),
            ChattingPage(),
            NotificationPage(),
            ProfilePage(userProfileId: currentUser.uid),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.white,
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey[600],
        backgroundColor: mainColor2,
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
        items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              label: '', icon: Icon(Icons.home), backgroundColor: mainColor2),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              label: '', icon: Icon(Icons.chat), backgroundColor: mainColor2),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              label: '',
              icon: Icon(Icons.new_releases),
              backgroundColor: mainColor2),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              label: '',
              icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle_outlined),
              backgroundColor: mainColor2),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
      userInfo();
      _pageController.animateToPage(index,
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500), curve: Curves.easeOut);
    });
  }
}
```

and Profile Page:

```
class ProfilePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String userProfileId;
  ProfilePage({this.userProfileId});

  @override
  _ProfilePageState createState() => _ProfilePageState();
}

class _ProfilePageState extends State<ProfilePage> {
  AuthService authService = new AuthService();

  final String currentOnlineUserId = currentUser?.uid;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  createProfileTopView() {
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: usersReference.doc(widget.userProfileId).get(),
        builder: (context, dataSnapshot) {
          if (!dataSnapshot.hasData) {
            return Center(
              child: Lottie.asset('assets/images/1.json'),
            );
          }

          User1 user = User1.fromDocument(dataSnapshot.data);

          return Padding(
            padding: context.paddingLow,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Row(
                  children: [
                    CircleAvatar(
                      radius: 45.0,
                      backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                      backgroundImage:
                          CachedNetworkImageProvider(user.photoLink),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                        child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Row(
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                          children: [
                            createColumns("Gönderi", 0),
                            createColumns("Takipçi", 0),
                            createColumns("Takip", 0),
                          ],
                        ),
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                          children: [createButton()],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ))
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        });
  }

  Column createColumns(String title, int count) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Text(
          count.toString(),
          style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w300, color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20.0),
        ),
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
          child: Text(
            title,
            style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 16.0),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  createButton() {
    bool ownProfile = currentOnlineUserId == widget.userProfileId;
    if (ownProfile) {
      return createButtonTitleAndFunction(
          title: "Profili düzenle", performFunction: editUserProfile);
    }
  }

  createButtonTitleAndFunction({String title, Function performFunction}) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 3.0),
      child: FlatButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        child: Container(
          width: 245.0,
          height: 26.0,
          child: Text(
            title,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
              color: Colors.grey,
            ),
          ),
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.black,
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6.0),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  editUserProfile() {
    Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) =>
                EditProfilePage(currentOnlineUserId: currentOnlineUserId)));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: mainColor,
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: mainColor2,
          title: Text(
            "Profil",
            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w300),
          ),
          actions: [
            IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.logout),
                onPressed: () {
                  authService.signOut();
                  Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginPage()));
                })
          ],
        ),
        body: ListView(
          children: [
            createProfileTopView(),
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

Also my UserModal:

```
class User1 {
  final String bio;
  final String email;
  final String linkedinLink;
  final String name;
  final String password;
  final String photoLink;
  final String uid;
  final String university;
  final String username;

  User1({
    this.bio,
    this.email,
    this.linkedinLink,
    this.name,
    this.password,
    this.photoLink,
    this.uid,
    this.university,
    this.username,
  });

  factory User1.fromDocument(DocumentSnapshot docx) {
    return User1(
      bio: docx['bio'],
      email: docx['email'],
      linkedinLink: docx['linkedinLink'],
      name: docx['name'],
      password: docx['password'],
      photoLink: docx['photoLink'],
      uid: docx.id,
      university: docx['university'],
      username: docx['username'],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the problem is here:

```
ProfilePage(userProfileId: currentUser.uid),
```

You're trying to pass `currentUser.uid` to the `ProfilePage`, but initially the `currentUser` is going to be `null`. So that explains the error.

The solution is to only render the `ProfilePage` when there is a current user, for example with:

```
currentUser != null ? ProfilePage(userProfileId: currentUser.uid) : Text("Loading user data..."),
```

Comment: appreciate sir it's worked :) we're following on firebase youtube channel  and big fan of you :)